# C++ : avoiding compiler dependencies vs. avoiding pointer overuse

Tags: c++, pointers, dependencies, compiler-construction, heap-memory

I know it's considered old-fashioned / out-of-date style to overuse pointers where they aren't necessary. However, I'm finding this ideal conflicts with another consideration of avoiding compiler dependencies.

Specifically, I can use forward declarations in a header file and avoid #include statements if member variables are pointers. But then this leads me to member variables of my own classes to be pointers, even when there's not really a good reason to do so.

Incidentally, I find using the Qt framework (which I enjoy) leads me to program in this java-esque everything-on-the-heap programming style since that's the way the interface is setup.

How do I weigh these two competing considerations?

Comment: did you measure performance? was heap allocation a bottleneck? if so, you could change only the hotspots

Comment: Don't over do it. The first goal is a good design, then comes the implementation. Compiler dependencies are just a detail of the implementation. Don't break your design just to improve compilation time, when most probably it won't matter at all (for small-medium sized projects)

Comment: I'd only use forward decl of stuff that's not in a header, but can be confined (as implementation detail) to an anonymous namespace of the implementing source file. Using a forward decl (instead of including the appropriate header) can also only generate errors and confusing: don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @David the compilation time / running time are indeed the least of my worries. The larger concern in avoiding pointer overuse isn't the incidental compiler time speedup, but the potential for memory leaks and other problems when there's not a great need to keep the objects on the heap.

Comment: @Walter that's interesting. Most references I've come across _recommend_ using forward declarations whenever possible as good practice, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @daj: Maybe I should have been clearer: avoid adding pointers to a design just to improve compilation times (compiler firewalls and such). If A contains a B, make B a member of A. Also note that usually a compiler firewall usually implies runtime cost (extra dereference, worse data locality...) in addition to the issues you mention: leaks, dangling pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.  Reducing dependencies is definitely a good thing,
per se, but it must be weighed against all of the other issues.
Using the compilation firewall idiom, for example, can move the
dependencies out of the header file, at the cost of one
allocation.

As for what QT does: it's a GUI framework, which (usually---I've
not looked at QT) means lots of polymorphism, and that most
classes have identity, and cannot be copied.  In such cases, you
usually do have to use dynamic allocation and work with
pointers.  The rule to avoid pointers mainly concerns objects
with value semantics.

(And by the way, there's nothing "old-fashioned" or
"out-of-date" about using too many pointers.  It's been the rule
since I started using C++, 25 years ago.)

Comment: Note: there are heapless implementation of PIMPL that work by reserving space (correctly aligned) in the class `pimpl<Object, 32, 4>`. Add in a `static_assert` in the constructor of `pimpl` to make sure it's big enough, and here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Qt needs it because it is a library that can be dynamically loaded.  Users can compile and link without having to worry about implementation details.  You can at runtime use many versions of Qt without having to recompile.  This is pretty powerful and flexible.  This wouldn't be possible if private object instances were used inside classes.